# Natural growth and decay rate of a bacteria culture

Tags: calculus, exponential-function

A bacteria culture initially contains $100$ cells and grows at a rate proportional to its size. After an hour the population has increased to $420$.

(a) Find an expression for the number of bacteria after $t$ hours.

(b) Find the number of bacteria after $3$ hours.

(c) Find the rate of growth after $3$ hours.

(d) When will the population reach $10,000$?

Comment: In which part did you run into a problem?

Comment: Listen, kid. If you want us to do your homework, then you have to pay. Send me $0.002$ bitcoins, and we have a deal. Your question is easy.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Note that the number of the bacteria $N$ increases with respect to time $t$ which suggests using the differential equation

> $$ \frac{dN(t)}{dt}=k N(t),\quad  k>0. $$

Solve the ode and use the initial condition $N(0)=100$ to find the constant of integration $C$ which resulted from solving the ode. Then advance to find $k$.